# Any ways to auto restart app when it crashes?

Tags: node.js, crash

The problem with my webapp is, for some reason it just creashes once in a week or two. When I see in the morning, the app is already down for 6 to 8 hours. While I'm on to find the cause and fix it, I just dont want any downtime in case of unexpected crashes.

What is the best way to achieve this?

It's a node + express server. Running on ubuntu 18.04 in aws ec2 t2.micro instance

Some solutions that hit me are :

1. Run the app inside an infinite loop either from node itself or from a shell file.
2. Run it as a service with Restart=Always

I'm looking for the easiest and the most reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

in your development environment, you can use [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) .

in your deployment environment, you can use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)